# What state is a view in after it is clicked (i.e. after the click is released)?

Tags: android, onclick, state, statelistdrawable, statelist

I have a clickable `ImageView` with a background color, and what I want is that its background color is changed when it is touched/clicked and *it should remain changed* even after the click is released, until something else is clicked.  For that I am writing a [state-list drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

I am using the `pressed` state, which is *while the view is being clicked.* I also want to know what state is the `ImageView` in after the click is released (until something else is clicked).

I am talking about the following states [given here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList):

- state_pressed
- state_focused
- state_hovered
- state_selected
- state_checkable
- state_checked
- state_enabled
- state_activated
- state_window_focused

Answer (score 0):

This is example !!!

```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawable);
    StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
    states.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed},
            ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.image_pressed, null));
    states.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused},
            ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.focused, null));
    states.addState(new int[]{},
            new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap));
    imageView.setImageDrawable(states);
```

Comment: SO you mean an `ImageView` is in **focused** state _after_ it is clicked?